# Why am I getting 0 results in my datagridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable

C# code:

```
command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);
command = createSQLQuery(command); // returns a valid SQL Query that returns results in SQL Management Studio 2012
//dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(command);
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
connection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(command);
debugMySQL();

public DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd) {
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, cn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    connection.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    connection.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

I am using C# with WinForm and developing with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Could it be the call to `connection.Close();` just before the call to `GetData`?

Comment: Its a good idea so I closed the connection After I set the DataSource. Then I get an error at da.Fill(dt) saying that "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: That first block of code is calling `GetData` twice. Is this intended?

Comment: No. I didn't see that until now. Thanks :)

Comment: It still produces the same error at da.Fill(dt) saying "There is already an open DataReader..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, but I'll try to answer as best as I could.

I think, normally, you need to define the type of command that you are going to pass into the `SqlCommand`, before executing that command.



    `command.Commandtype = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`


(OR)


    `command.CommandText = CommandType.Text;`

You can set the SQL query in string value after that.


    `command.CommandText = "";   // your SQL query, or the name of the stored procedure`

Also, you don't need to set the `DataSource` of the grid twice. You only need to set it after you got the result of you SQL query execution is returned.
However you receive the result is your choice. But, you seemed to executed the command twice, with both `GetData()` method and `command.ExecuteReader()` method. And also, you are setting the `DataSource` of your grid twice too.

I think even if you managed to set up the command object properly, because of your double executions, data might be lost somehow between them.

And, by the way, what data type is returned from the `createSQLQuery()` method. You said it returned a valid SQL Query, but is it returned a valid sql query value in `string`, or your custom command object to parse into the `SqlCommand`?

I'll include the best operable procedure I know for reading from the SQL database and bind that data into the grid control.

```
// I suppose you get the connection object as 'con'
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "...";   // You desired SQL query goes here, or if you want to execute a stored procedure, set the command type as 'StoredProcedure' and text as sp name.

SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
dap.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
dap.Fill(tbl);
<br>
if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grid.DataSource = tbl;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

I recommend you to receive the result as `DataTable` rather than `SqlDataReader`. Cause `DataTable` is more flexible and versatile.

Comment: P.S., you don't even need to open and close the connection if you fill the DataTable with SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: And, how about your sql query? Does it work properly as you intended? It might not be the coding problem, but the query execution...

Comment: The Query works fine. I ran it several times in SQL Management Studio. The code for debugMySQL shows me the query that should execute and that also works fine.

Comment: It looks like tbl.Rows.Count is always 0. How do I fix it?

Comment: Even if the sp has parameters, you can set the parameters values by writing like this... `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", yourvalue);` .. for each of the parameters.

Comment: And, @spajce... thz for the formatting. I had connection problems when I post the answer... :-)

Comment: @softwareisfun... if your `tbl.Rows.Count` comes as 0, then it's not the program error. You might need to check out the query. Maybe, it needs some parameters or something...

Answer (score 0):

```
        var command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = createSQLQuery(command);
        command.Connection = connection;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(command);

        debugMySQL();

    }

    public DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your `return dt;`, try adding this:

```
if(dt.row.count > 0)
{
    var something =dt[0][0];
}
```

Then, put a breakpoint in the `if` statement and see if you get anything back.